# Parsing and reformatting an object to a simple javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Suppose I have an object from that has a key and value pair and I want to reformat it into a simple javascript array:

```
 var obj = {STRUCTURE_: '004A006', SEG_ID: '04081591__,0.12,0.25,65850'}
```

that looks like this:

```
 ['004A006', '04081591__,0.12,0.25,65850']
```

Whats the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the object's enumerable property values:

```js
var obj = {STRUCTURE_: '004A006', SEG_ID: '04081591__,0.12,0.25,65850'}

const res = Object.values(obj)

console.log(res)
```